# How to 'Freeze' the UI (main window) when mouse is hovering over

Tags: wpf, triggers, freeze, ismouseover

What I want to achieve is that when the mouse is hovering over the main window, all the UI elements should freeze, which I think can be done by setting Window.IsEnabled to false, and after the mouse leaves the main window, everything should be back to normal.

I've tried to define a property trigger in a style targetting Window, but it doesn't work. The code is as lollow,

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Window.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Window.IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

In fact this kind of property trigger wouldn't work on Grid either. Can anyone make some explanations?

I also tried to explicitly use the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events on Window, and set the disable/enable logic in the handlers. This works. I wonder if it's possible to do this in XAML?

Comment: Hmm.... If you're disabling input entirely, don't forget to disable touch and keyboard as well!

Comment: how to disable the touch and keyboard?

Comment: My point is that I could probably alt+tab over to your program if I wanted to interact with it using the keyboard, since you're only responding to mouse events. You should try to detect any input focus, but even then, if you have to create this sort of weird behavior... you may want to rethink your design?

Answer (score 0):

Well to be honest I don't know why your code doesn't work, I think it goes in some kind of conflict but I don't know why

Anyway you can do it in XAML using eventsetter, It's not so elegant but it works

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard Name="sb">
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled" >
                    <BooleanKeyFrameCollection>
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="0:0:0:1"></DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame>
                    </BooleanKeyFrameCollection>
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```